# How to use the pwd as a filename

Tags: bash

I need to go through a whole set of subdirectories, and each time it finds a subdirectory named 0, it has to go inside it. Once there, I need to execute a tar command to compact some files.

I tried the following

```
find . -type d -name "0" -exec sh -c '(cd {} && tar -cvf filename.tar ../PARFILE RS* && cp filename.tar ~/home/directoryForTransfer/)' ';'
```

which seems to work. However, because this is done in many directories named 0, it will always overwrite the previous filename.tar one (and I lose the info about where it was created).

One way to solve this would be to use the $pwd as the filename (+.tar at the end).

I tried double ticks, backticks, etc, but I never manage to get the correct filename.

```
"$PWD"".tar", `$PWD.tar`, etc
```

Any idea? Any other way is ok, as long as I can link the name of the file with the directory it was created.

I'd need this to transfer the directoryToTransfer easily from the cluster to my home computer.

Comment: How about creating a single tar file that contains all the files you are interested in using the directory structure you already have?  I think this would be much simpler to deal with.

Comment: @anubhava Yes, each 0 directory needs to have a tar file.

Comment: @5gon12eder I didn't think of that. So, I could tar my whole tree (including the structure with subdirectories), where the only files that are actually included are the ones in my 0 directories? How would you do that?

Comment: The RS* files are in the 0 directory, the PARFILE are in the subdirectory of the 0 directory (and some other files too in these to levels, but I did simplify it for the sake of clarity)

Comment: @Nigu Thre are a couple of approaches I can think of.  One would be to append the file names (full paths) you want to tar to some text file (using a simple modification of your `find` command) and then use `tar`'s `--files-from` option (probably together with `--transform` to get rid of common prefixes and avoid absolute paths in your archive).  Or you could try `tar`'s `--append` option.

Comment: @5gon12ceder Thanks, I learned some new way to deal with the problem. I'll accept petersohn answer because it's the one closest to what I intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `"${PWD//\//_}.tar"`. However you have to use `bash -c` instead of `sh -c`.

**Edit:**

So now your code should look like this:

```
find . -type d -name "0" -exec bash -c 'cd {} && tar -cvf filename.tar ../PARFILE RS* && cp filename.tar ~/home/directoryForTransfer/"${PWD//\//_}.tar"' ';'
```

I personally don't really like the using `-exec` flag for `find` as it makes the code less readable and also forks a new process for each file. I would do it like this, which should work unless a filename somewhere contains a newline (which is very unlikely).

```
while read dir; do
    cd {} && tar -cvf filename.tar ../PARFILE RS* && cp filename.tar ~/home/directoryForTransfer/"${PWD//\//_}.tar"
done < <(find . -type d -name "0")
```

But this is just my personal preference. The `-exec` variant should work too.

Comment: Thanks. this seems to work. I'll wait a bit before accepting, some nice propositions have been made in the comments above.

Comment: And on my mac, the sh did the trick, but maybe that's related to my machine.

Comment: Note that there is a potential clash between `foo/bar/baz` and `foo/bar_baz`.  May be a pedantic concern but I like to be paranoid with such things.

Comment: @5gon12eder: Of course you can use another separator that's less likely to interfere.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `-execdir` option in `find` to descend in each found directory and then run the `tar` command to greatly simplify your `tar` command:

```
find . -type d -name "0" -execdir tar -cvf filename.tar RS* \;
```

If you want tar file to be created in `~/home/directoryForTransfer/` then use:

```
find . -type d -name "0" -execdir tar -cvf ~/home/directoryForTransfer/filename.tar RS* \;
```

Comment: I'll accept @petersohn's answer because it's the one closest to what I intended. But Thanks!